# Java Partition Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, partitioning

I'm looking for an recursive algorithm for partitioning a number in k parts.

For exemple :

```
P(5,2) > { {1,4},{2,3} }
P(7,2) > { {1,6},{2,5},{3,4} }
P(5,3) > { {1,1,3},{1,2,2} }
```

In Java, but it can be another langage.

My code currently

```
    public static void partition(int n, int k) {
        partition(n, k, " ");
    }

    public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
            partition(n-i, i, prefix + " " + i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and you tried what so far?

Comment: Step 1) take prime factors. Step 2) apply binomial theorem. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6999554/2071828).

Comment: I have a basic algorithm like that :
public static void partition(int n, int k) {
        partition(n, k, " ");
    }
    public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }
  
        for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
            partition(n-i, i, prefix + " " + i);
        }
    }

Comment: Please post this in your question. It's much more useful there.

Comment: Does you current code produce the desired output? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to partition `n` in exactly `k` numbers, each at least one (1).

I would first check that `n >= k` and `k >= 1` because otherwise it’s not possible (leave the corner case n = k = 0).

In your recursive call, since you are appending exactly one number to `prefix`, I think you should pass `max - 1` as the second argument to ensure that you will end up with exactly `k` partitions.

There may be other issues. If you tell us your current output, it may be easier to see.